# FileNotFound error in python 3 even though I see the file

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, stemming, porter-stemmer

I'm still relatively new to coding and I am writing a loop so I can make a model with stemmed files for a digital humanities course. I inputted:

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
ps = PorterStemmer()

list_stemmed_files = []
for i in filenames:
    with open (str(i),'r') as file:
        readFile = file.read()
        tokenized_file = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(readFile)
        stemmed_file = [ps.stem(word) for word in tokenized_file]
        list_stemmed_files.append(stemmed_file)
```

but I keep getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-448-2c39e0a51e22> in <module>
      5 list_stemmed_files = []
      6 for i in filenames:
----> 7     with open (str(i),'r') as file:
      8         readFile = file.read()
      9         tokenized_file = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(readFile)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'K077983.000.txt'
```

When I print my folder `filenames`
I get

```
['K077983.000.txt',
 'K096120.018.txt',
 'K036380.000.txt',
 'K039073.000.txt',
 'K057408.000.txt',
 'K040172.000.txt',
 'K050373.000.txt',
 'K041500.000.txt',
 'K061112.000.txt',
 'K119752.000.txt',
 'K025532.001.txt',
 'K020298.000.txt',
 'K015852.000.txt',
 'K010695.000.txt',
 'K062887.000.txt']
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Are the files stored in the same directory as your Python program? If not, you need to specify a relative or absolute path to the files when opening them. For instance, if your program is in the directory **program_folder** and your files are in the directory **program_folder\file_folder**, you will need to add the string "file_folder\" to the beginning of the files when opening them.

Comment: FileNotFoundError is self-explanatory. You are specifying a relative pathname. In fact, it's just a filename and is therefore expected to be found in your current working directory. Try using an absolute pathname

Comment: Do you have any idea how often this error shows up here?  It's always the same problem, the default directory is not where the files are located.  And the best fix is always the same, use a full absolute path for the filename.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try adding the path to the directory that has the list of files you are looping through. You can import 'os' library for this and try the following:

```
import os
import nltk
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
ps = PorterStemmer()
file_path = 'path/to/directory/' # you should use the path to your directory here

list_stemmed_files = []
for i in filenames:
    with open (os.path.join(file_path,i),'r') as file:
        readFile = file.read()
        tokenized_file = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(readFile)
        stemmed_file = [ps.stem(word) for word in tokenized_file]
        list_stemmed_files.append(stemmed_file)
```